# How to get django-all auth to pass data to custom user model?

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I'm making a site in Django using django-allauth for authentication.

I've created a custom user class in accounts.models to add a custom field, FavouriteTeam.

The issue I have is that the form renders fine and submits formdata for fav_team fine (as inspected in Chrome dev tools) but the fav_team entry doesn't get stored to user.FavouriteTeam and I can't figure out why.

I can go into the Django shell, import my User class from accounts.models, query for a user, add a .FavouriteTeam, and save just fine.  It's just that the form doesn't seem to save the data into the new User instance for some reason.

I'm guessing it's due to the way django-allauth interacts with custom user models but I can't figure it out for the life of me.  I've seen some similar posts but none have a situation like this or have a solution that seems to work for me.

Any ideas?

**accounts.models: -**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    FavouriteTeam = models.ForeignKey('predictor.Team', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

**accounts.forms: -**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from .models import User
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm
from predictor.models import Team
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class CustomSignupForm(SignupForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='First Name')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Last Name')
    fav_team = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Team.objects.all(), empty_label=None, label='Favourite Team')

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()

    def signup(self, request, user):
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.FavouriteTeam = self.cleaned_data['fav_team']
        user.save()
        return user
```

**predictor.models: -**

```
class Team(models.Model):
    ShortName = models.CharField(max_length=4, primary_key=True)
    Town = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Nickname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Conference = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=True, blank=True)
    Division  = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True, blank=True)
    ConfDiv = models.CharField(max_length=9, null=True, blank=True)
    Logo = models.ImageField(default='football.png', upload_to='logos')


    def __str__(self):
        return('{} {}'.format(self.Town, self.Nickname))

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.ConfDiv = str(self.Conference)+" "+str(self.Division)
        super(Team, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: put your view here

Comment: @BakhtiyarBekbergen - I haven't set up a particular view for it.  In my accounts.urls file I have the below: -

path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls'))

So I assume it uses some kind of built in allauth view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone looking at this and suffering the same issue, I eventually found the solution  to be as below.

Firstly, I had to create adpaters.py within my accounts app and fill in the below: -

```
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter

class AccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def save_user(self, request, user, form, commit=False):
        data = form.cleaned_data
        user.email = data['email']
        user.first_name = data['first_name']
        user.last_name = data['last_name']
        user.FavouriteTeam = data['fav_team']
        if 'password1' in data:
            user.set_password(data['password1'])
        else:
            user.set_unusable_password()
        self.populate_username(request, user)
        user.save()
        return user
```

Then I had to referenced the new account adapter in my project's settings.py file as below: -

```
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = "accounts.adapters.AccountAdapter"
```

Hope that helps someone in the future.